# PHP Outgoing/External link

Tags: php, external

Hi I'm looking to implement a similar feature to that seen on deviantART if a person clicks onto an external link: example: http://www.deviantart.com/users/outgoing?http://driz.co.uk/

What would be the best way of implementing such a feature? From the looks of it on dA they just edit all the external links to have the `http://www.deviantart.com/users/outgoing?` prefix and then show that page which allows them to visit the site or return. So perhaps I'd need someway of implementing a way to check which links are NOT on the current domain and then prefix them with a special url to show a stepping stone page.

Or perhaps just appending the `rel="external"` to the links and then somehow for all links that have the rel tag of external go to page like that or perhaps show a dialog showing the same message.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

For the user input html use a regular expression:

```
<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"']?([^\"' >]+)[\"' >]
```

where $1 will be the href, now you can test against:

```
(\w:\/{2})?([\w\.]+)
```

if $2 is not one of your domains you need to rewrite the href, so locate the position of $1 in the first regexp (strpos in php) and add your mask url

```
http://yourdomain.com/maskurl?
```

The query string as is will be the url you want to redirect to

By the other side if you are printing the links with a given url you need to pass only the second one.

The first regexp from here: http://www.onaje.net/content/working-regular-expressions-href-url-extractor and the other was written by me, but tested none.

Answer (score 2):

The detection part: a link only needs this kind of decoration if it's an user-provided, clickable link. You already have the infrastructure to turn user-provided links into clickable links (otherwise, you have a major security issue), so all you need to do is plug all those links into a decorator function.

The decoration part: have a function accept an URL argument. If the first part of the argument is "http://your.domain.name", or if it's a relative link (does not start with a protocol like http://), leave it alone. Otherwise:

```
$url = "http://your.domain.name/outgoing.php?".urlencode($url);
```

This will ensure that any unprotected characters in the original URL are properly escaped.

The redirection part: in the `outgoing.php` script simply look inside `array_keys($_GET)` to find the URL and display the appropriate page.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to change your links where the new URL would be a script of your own that redirects users based on the query string. If you want to keep the same URL structure as deviantArt, use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to grab the URL in your redirect script.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent help Netcoder. This is the full php of the The redirection part:

```
<?php

$redirect = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'';

?>

<html><head>

<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  


<title>Your Page title</title>

</head><body>

your Site Content

</body>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

setTimeout("location.href ='<?php echo $redirect ?>'",30);

</script>

</html>
```

> **your Site Content** is what you want to show. **30** is the time in
>   seconds to wait before the redirection. Save it as outgoing.php (or
>   anything)

External link must be in this format : http://your-nice-domain.com/outgoing.php?http://the-external-domain.com/external-path.any

**Important** :

1. Robot out this php file from robots.txt
2. It will be the same like dA except : the redirection is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could approach this, depending on how the pages are generated. If all the links are being generated by PHP, then it could easily be done by comparing the URL of the link to that of the site. If they are different, prepend your passthough page to the beginning of the URL, similar to how DA did it.

I just completed a script to add external link icons next to each link, similar to how Wikipedia does it. For this particular site, I had to work with many pages that have static content. Using the PHP method I mentioned above, would not work well for this. Instead I implemented something in Javascript. Using jQuery, I select all anchor tags that start with "http://" or "https://", then I cycle through each one to check if the domain matches my current one. If it is different, I add the icon next to the link. You could do similar, but instead prepend the href of the anchor with your passthough page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$html = '<a href="http://google.com/somethingelsewhere">Something</a>'
      . '<a href="http://example.com/somethinginmysite">My site!</a>';

echo preg_replace_callback('/<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*["\']?([^"\' >]+)["\' >]/', function($m) {
     // initialise the data variable from your object
     $link = $m[1];

     // early return
     if(strpos($link, 'http://example') === 0) return $m[0];

     $linklen = strlen($m[1]);
     $start = strlen($m[0]) - $linklen - 1;

     $replacement = 'http://example.com/mymask?link=' . urlencode($link);
     return substr_replace($m[0], $replacement, $start, $linklen);
}, $html);
```